# externalizar strings java

Tags: java, eclipse, string

A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable.

Tengo un proyecto enorme de java y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de externalizar todos los *String* a constantes de todos los ficheros ***.java**

(Eclipse) Source - Externalize string únicamente lo hace en un fichero e ir uno por uno es inviable. Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No tienes un ejemplo de lo que has hecho hasta el momento?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar un [archivo-de-propiedades](/questions/tagged/archivo-de-propiedades) .properties

Te adjunto un ejemplo...

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestPropeties {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String resourceName = "archivo.properties";
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        prop.load(resourceStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error al cargar el archivo de propiedades");
    }
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("clave"));
    }
}
```

En donde archivo.properties tiene la información de esta manera

```
clave=valor
clave2=valor2
```

Ese archivo properties puede ser abierto desde cualquier clase que requieras.